# Why does element be deleted together which has the attribute of contenteditable=false

Tags: html, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p contenteditable="false">1</p>
    <p contenteditable="false">2</p>
    <p contenteditable="false">3</p>
    <p contenteditable="true">4</p>
    <p contenteditable="true">5</p>
</div>
```

When I press the "BackSpace" key, these continuous elements which have the attribute of contenteditable=false will be deleted all of them !

And moreover,their behavior would be completely different if I change the element of "<p>" to the element of "<span>"

This is a bug or characteristic?

Example: [The example of program](https://jsfiddle.net/o95mhupo/)

And How to just delete an element of "<p>" which has attribute of contenteditable=false?

Answer (score 0):

For situations that use the span element, this is a bug when using an element that is not a block element : 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=439808